# How to make yui2 responsive

Tags: responsive-design, yui2

I am using yui2 (I know it is archived now but I had hands on experience with this version and did not have time to learn yui3 due to tight deadline) in some of the pages of my project.The pages without yui listing are made responsive for mobile view using responsive css.But now the pages with yui2 design are not responsive.I want to know if I can add lines of code so that it can become responsive.Please help.

Answer (score 0):

YUI or not, you can use Pure CSS grids:  http://purecss.io/grids/#pure-responsive-grids

Comment: dear @user3129262 :the table is created dynamically from server side data and the styles it gets via previously imported css files.Can you guide how do I insert it to my code

Comment: I guess you mean you are using HTML table elements to create your grids.  In that case, AFAIK, responsiveness is out of the question since a row won't  break into a second line naturally, unless you do some tough CSS tinkering, which not all browsers will like.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:
follow steps given here:https://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/

in the css provided replace table,td etc with `#uryuidivname table,#urdivname td`